# List of all users who were deactivated in the last month/given date range in Active directory

Tags: c#

I can able to find out if the user is Active or not in AD by below code.

```
public class ADService
{
    public bool? FindAccountStatusByEmail(string email)
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher())
        {
            dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*)(mail=" + email.Trim() + "))";
            SearchResult sResult = dSearch.FindOne();
            if (sResult != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = sResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                return IsActive(de);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
    {
        if (de.NativeGuid == null) return false;

        int flags = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

        return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
    }
}
```

But I need to generate a list of deactivated user in the last month/given date range in Active directory using C#.

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here it is. I have developed it. My objective is: I need to find deactivated uses who were deactivated since last 'x' days.

`whenChanged` - Sometimes it is useful to be able to search for objects in Active Directory based on when they were changed.
We can user this attribute like any other in our LDAP queries, the only thing to watch is the syntax of the date/time value. The syntax of this attribute is like this:
`YYYYMMDDHHmmss.sZ` (The capital Z at the end is mandatory and denotes Zulu time, which is the same as GMT.)

When we want to query Active Directory for user class objects that are disabled, the attribute that holds this information is the `userAccountControl` attribute. `userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803` will have Bit 2 set if the account is disabled. See more [userAccountControl](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm)

Finally the code is:

```
    public StringBuilder FindDisabledAccount(int sinceDay)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-sinceDay);
        try
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher())
            {
                dSearch.PageSize = 100;
                dSearch.CacheResults = false;

                string fromDateStr = fromDate.Year.ToString() + fromDate.Month.ToString("D2") + fromDate.Day.ToString("D2") + "000000.0Z";
                string toDateStr = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("D2") + (DateTime.Today.Day + 1).ToString("D2") + "000000.0Z";

                dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
                 + "(whenChanged>=" + fromDateStr + ")(whenChanged<=" + toDateStr + "))";

                dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
                dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DisplayName");
                dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenChanged");

                using (var sResult = dSearch.FindAll())
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("EmpId,Name,Email,IsActive,LastChangedDate");
                    foreach (SearchResult result in sResult)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                        sb.AppendLine(de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value + "," + de.Properties["DisplayName"].Value + "," + de.Properties["mail"].Value + ",FALSE," + de.Properties["whenChanged"].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return sb;
    }
```